# Upgrading OS X 10.6.8 to Mavericks on MB Air

Tags: macbook-pro

As we all know Maverics is not available on AppStore anymore so I downloaded my "purchased" Mavericks from another MB Pro I have. Someone here asked the similiar question and several people advised to make a bootable usb-drive and restore the system from it.
My questions is - can I use the 5,33Gb file I downloaded from "purchased" to simply upgrade without the need to backup my MB Air first? Should I copy the file to a specific folder or may just use Desktop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option would be to create a bootable USB drive and install from there. But if you need to do it via a local file, I would copy the Upgrader File to the /Applications folder of the MB Air.

Yes, you should make a backup. Especially since you are jumping a couple versions of the OS.

(In truth, I have not had a problem with any of the 30 or 40 upgrades I have done with Mac OS X in the last 4 or 5 years. But I always had a backup, unless I was planning on wiping the system clean. )

Comment: Why is it the best option to use bootable USB drive? Having a backup is a good idea in case something goes wrong. But in case I restore OS it will erase the data, right? Why not just upgrade and see if I need to use my backup? Is there any reason besides having a "clean" and more stable Mavericks?

Comment: It gives you a few more options if anything goes wrong, such as using Disk Utility to fix the internal drive. Additionally, it doesn't take up space on the internal drive. I am not sure how much free space a system needs for an upgrade, but I would plan on 3 times the amount of the upgrader file. That is if the upgrade file is 5.33GB, I would make sure the system had 16GB free before I put the upgrade on it. This is not a hard rule, but I feel anything less could lead to problems.